# Why do i keep getting the NG0203 error when i build my Angular app using esbuild?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, esbuild

Im trying to migrate to esbuild to build my Angular application. I've completed everything i needed to do, but i keep seeing this error being logged in the console:

`Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with` runInInjectionContext

I've tried everything thats described here, at 'Using application builder': https://angular.io/guide/esbuild

My app.config.ts looks like this:

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    importProvidersFrom(
      BrowserModule,
      SharedModule,
      DataSetModule,
      LookUpTablesModule,
      NormsModule,
      StoreModule.forRoot({
        mappings: mappingsReducer,
        auth: authReducer,
      }),
      EffectsModule.forRoot([AuthEffects])
    ),
    provideAnimations(),
    provideHttpClient(),
    provideRouter(routes),
  ],
};
```

And i inject classes like this, which worked with the former builder:

````
constructor(
    private router: Router,
    public excelDownload: ExcelDownloadService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private dataSetService: DataSetService
  ) {} ```

Edit: this is the exact error that is being logged:
`ERROR Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `runInInjectionContext`. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0203
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:985:15)
    at ɵɵinject3 (core.mjs:998:42)
    at Object.factory (core.mjs:27529:46)
    at core.mjs:6247:43
    at runInInjectorProfilerContext (core.mjs:948:9)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.mjs:6246:17)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:6114:33)
    at definition.getStandaloneInjector (core.mjs:27545:31)
    at ComponentFactory.create (core.mjs:15477:57)
    at _ApplicationRef.bootstrap (core.mjs:31863:42)`
````

Comment: Are you sure you are not using `inject` function anywhere in your app? Using it outside injection context will throw this error. For example trying to inject dependencies in `ngOnInit` hook. See https://angular.io/errors/NG0203

Comment: No, i dont use inject() anywhere in my code. I only inject dependencies like i showed in the example above.

Comment: Could you please share more of your code? All of it would be great. `inject` function is utilized internally by other util functions. Signals? `computed`? `takeUntilDestroyed`? It might be `AuthEffects` declaration suspected... or `mappingsReducer`, or `authReducer`...

Comment: The problem seems to occur ever since i bootstrap the application like this:

`
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig).catch((err) =>
  console.error(err)
);
 `

``` 
@Injectable()
export class AuthEffects {
  constructor(private actions$: Actions, private authService: AuthService) {}

  login$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(fetchUser),
      mergeMap(() =>
        this.authService.fetchUser().pipe(
          map((user) => setUser({ user })),
          catchError((error) => of())
        )
      )
    )
  );
}

```

Comment: Wait… that code is in main.ts..? Including the AuthEffects class..?

Comment: only the bootstrapApplication() code is in main.ts, the autheffects class and appConfig constant are each in seperate files

Answer (score 0):

Please remove these modules one by one to identify the problematic one. The remaining imports you can move to the imports of Root component if the root component is standalone, if not, you can add to the imports array of app module!

Instead of `BrowserModule` use `CommonModule`, which might give you some error!

```
@Component({
    imports: [
      CommonModule,
      SharedModule,
      DataSetModule,
      LookUpTablesModule,
      NormsModule,
    ]
})
export class App {

}
```

In my opinion, only these two might be needed for `importProvidersFrom`

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    importProvidersFrom(
      StoreModule.forRoot({
        mappings: mappingsReducer,
        auth: authReducer,
      }),
      EffectsModule.forRoot([AuthEffects])
    ),
    provideAnimations(),
    provideHttpClient(),
    provideRouter(routes),
  ],
};
```